# Finding $x$ and $y$ coordinates using forces and velocity.

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

please can I have some help with this question"

"A $0.1$kg inflatable ball floats on the surface of the sea. The current frin the water underneath the ball exerts a force   $C=(2i + j)N$ and the wind exerts a force of $W=(3i - 2j)N$ . Initially the ball is at the origin ans has velocity $(1i +1j) ms^-1$.

Find the $X$ and $Y$ coordinates of the ball $t$ seconds later."

What I did first was find the resultant force on the ball then rearranged $F=Ma$ to find the acceleration. I don't know what to do next. I'm guessing you use suvat split into horizontal and vertical components but I don't understand which values I have to substitute into the equations.

Any help/ ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration would be a constant vector. So use equations of motion to get velocity t seconds later:
$\vec v=\vec u +\vec a t$ where $\vec u$ is the initial velocity vector and $\vec v$ is the final velocity vector.
(This equation comes from the definition of acceleration: $\vec a=\frac {\vec v-\vec u} t$)

Comment: The displacement is average velocity $(=\frac {\vec u + \vec v} 2 )$ multiplied by time. So$ \vec r= xi+yj -(x_0i+y_0j)=t\frac {\vec u + \vec v} 2 $ where $(x_0i+y_0j)$ is the position at $t=0$